# Enabling feed tracking when creating scratch org not possible?

Tags: salesforcedx, cli, tracking, mdapi

So, currently, there is no way to enable feed tracking for a standard object, during scratch org creation. This includes all settings in scratch org definition file and/or using an org shape.

The issue is that if the project has a standard object with feed enabled, pushing the metadata directly after scratch org creation will guarantee an error, stating that (for example) "Error Task The entity: Task does not have feeds enabled".

Ideally we wouldn't want to have to enable it through the UI, so is there any workaround this please?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

After looking at each xml tag in the "problem" tag is the following:

```
<recordTypeTrackFeedHistory>true</recordTypeTrackFeedHistory>
```

And this tag simply allows the feed tracking of the Record Type of the object. What I think is happening is, Salesforce is deploying the object and executing this tag first, without enabling feed first, which may be the reason the error is thrown.

So, I ended up removing this tag, which allowed me to push the Task.object-meta.xml with the following tag

```
<enableFeeds>true</enableFeeds>
```